# Concerning AJAX, PHP, and processing forms

Tags: php, ajax

I want to use AJAX to process a simple login form. I thought it'd be pretty easy, but I just can't get it all to work.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX Login</title>
<script type="text/javscript">
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    function logIn() {
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
            var obj = document.getElementById("show");
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "login.php");

            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4
                   && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
                        obj.innerHtml = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                    }
                }

                XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
            }
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type="username" name="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" \ /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" onclick="logIn();" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="show">should go here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
$username = "andrew";
$password = "andrew";

if($_POST['username'] != "") {
    if($_POST['password'] != "") {
        if(($_POST['username'] == $username) && ($_POST['password'] == $password)) {
            echo "Login Success!";
            }
            else {
                echo "Login Failure!";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "You didn't enter a password";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "You didn't enter a username";
                }
?>
```

When I click the "Login" button, nothing happens. :(

Comment: I recommend you use some JavaScript library, for example jQuery. That makes AJAX so much easier and is working on all (or almost all) browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click login on that form it submits back to the source URL. To prevent this you should really change your event handler to either this:

```
function logIn() {
  ...
  return false;
}
```

Alternatively you can do it from the submit handler on the form instead of the click handler on the submit button.

Secondly, to do AJAX cross-browser you need about 6 fallback conditions, not just XmlHttpRequest. See [Getting Started with AJAX and the XMLHttpRequest Object](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=667416&seqNum=2).

In all honesty, for AJAX there's no way I'd consider doing it without a helper library. My preferred choice is jQuery, in which case the code ends up looking like this:

```
<form id="loginform" method="post">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="username" id="username" name="username" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" \ /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="login" value="Login"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#login").click(function() {
    $("#show").load("login.php", {
      username: $("#username").val(),
      password: $("#password").val()
    }, function() {
      $("#loginform").hide(); // for example
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Half right: because the `onclick` event isn't cancelled, the form does trigger a submit.  But the AJAX `.send()` doesn't get called until the `logIn()` function fires, which isn't on page startup.

Comment: Also, while cross-browser compatibility is important, and jQuery definitely does make the job easier, `XmlHttpRequest` is supported by all the major browsers these days.  So just using it without a fallback isn't as crazy as it used to be.

Comment: I guess that'll solve my problem. I've only messed with jQuery a little (played around with it when I found out about it), but recently I've been bored so I picked up an AJAX book at my school's library. Is there any point going through it and trying to learn AJAX, or should I go find some jQuery tutorials and attempt to learn that?

Comment: In all honesty I consider jQuery a "must-have" for Javascript development, particularly for Ajax. It just solves way too many cross-browser problems and is so small (under 20K and cacheable). IMHO there's just no reason (any more) to know the right sequence of objects to create to do a cross-browser XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Look into the jQuery form plugin.  Its as simple as:

<form action="login.php" id="loginForm">
$('#loginForm').ajaxForm();

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: Cross browser XMLHttpRequest isn't the trial it once was. Test for `window.XMLHttpRequest`, use `ActiveXObject` as a fallback for IE6... that's it, job done. Personally I wouldn't drag in jQuery for something as simple as this form. I'd second moving the event to `form.onsubmit` instead of a button click you can't rely on. Best: make the form work by itself as a normal HTML form pointing to login.php, then add progressive-enhancement XMLHttpRequest sauce to make it nicer where JavaScript and XHR are available.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script is expecting variables to be passed as an HTTP POST request, but your `XMLHTTPRequest` is doing a GET request.

You're also doing `XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);` -- instead, you should be passing your POST data to the `.send()` method.

As others have pointed out, using a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) will make this kind of thing a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the logIn() function anywhere. Most likely, it belongs into the onsubmit event of the form. Don't forget to

```
return false;
```

at the end.

Comment: Nope, he's got an `<input type="submit">` with `onclick="logIn();"`, so that isn't the issue.  But the `return false;` is a good idea, because you want to cancel the `onclick` event, as it would otherwise trigger an `onsubmit`.